# How to do texture edge padding for tiling correctly?

Tags: xna, textures, filtering, padding, xna-4.0

My aim is to draw a set of texures (128x128 pixels) as (gap-less) tiles without filtering artifacts in XNA.

Currently, I use for example 25 x 15 fully opaque tiles (alpha is always 255) in x-y to create a background image in a game, or a similar number of semi-transparent tiles to create the game "terrain" (foreground). In both cases, the tiles are scaled and drawn using floating-point positions. As it is known, to avoid filtering artifacts (like small but visible gaps, or unwanted color overlaps at the tile borders) one has to do "**edge padding**" which is described as adding an additional fringe of a width of one pixel and using the color of adjacent pixels for the added pixels. Discussions about this issue can be found for example [here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/1676/8432.aspx#8432). An example image of this issue from our game can be found below.

However, I do not really understand how to do this - technically, and specifically in XNA.

**(1)** When adding a fringe of one pixel width, my tiles would then be 129 x 129 and the overlapping fringes would create quite visible artifacts of their own.

**(2)** Alternatively, once could add the padding pixels but then not draw the full 129x129 pixel texture but only its "center" (without the fringe) e.g. by choosing the source rectangle of this texture to be (1,1,128,128). But are then the padding pixels not simply ignored or is the filtering hardware really using this information?

So basically, I wonder how this is done properly? :-)

**Example image of filtering issue from game**: Unwanted vertical gap in brown foreground tiles.
[image: Example image from game]

Comment: The issue is with partial pixels - You draw an image of size (w,h) onto a screen area of size (wk, hk) and unless this gives an exact integer result (which it won't), you end up needing additional information from surrounding pixels for scaling. But if there is no more texture, this would be transparent, black or white (depending on implementation) - So you need overlapping textures, from which you only draw non-overlapping areas - the engine should do the rest, but I have no idea about XNA :)